# How to share Docker for Mac images with ones in docker-machine?

Tags: macos, docker, virtualbox, iot, docker-machine

So I am on a mac and I need USB forwarded into docker image. Thus I spin up `docker-machine` on `virtualbox` with usb forwarding. The only thing is that it does not see my docker images from Docker for Mac and I really would like to share them. How to do such thing?

Comment: Best choice: `docker push`.  Working choice: `docker save`.

Comment: can we somehow map files\folders for docker in the boot2docker VM to see docker files in the mac OS?

Comment: No, they’re separate virtual machines and using different virtualization technologies.  Good third choice: re-run `docker build` for each of your local images in the third environment.